# Send URL from Google Chrome to c# Application

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I'm writing a Download Manager in c# for learning purposes.

I've searched on Google but i cannot find anything about this question..

What i want to do, is to add downloads into my c# Download Manager automatically from Chrome, so, use my c# Download Manager instead to use the Chrome one.

I know it's possible to do it, (maybe not in c#) but if you know FDM (Free Download Manager) it does have this option to intercept Downloads from browsers..

So i have two question for you guys:

**It is possible in C# - WPF?**

**If yes, How?**

I've not tried anything, because i do not know how to do it, and also i've not found any example or discussions that can point me in the right direction.

I hope someone can help me out.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Ok, i already know that i need a chrome extension. I never developed one but this it's not a problem.. there are a lot of tutorial where i can learn from.. 
Anyway, i know my question isn't clear, i try to explain better what i want to know:

First, The Chrome extension.. So, i know i need it to send data to my Application. I need some example on how to do it... So, question 1: **How to Write a Chrome Extension to pass parameters to a C# Application?**

Second.. C# part.. **How to get the parameters from the chrome extension and then send it to the download method? In this case it's a method with one URI param.**

I'm not asking actual code. But an explanation, or an existing example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a [chrome extension.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)

FDM registers itself as an extension, this extension passes in parameters and launches the app.

To break down the steps:

1. You have your c# app listening on a port.
2. You create an extension that sends data via [Google's Cross Extension Messaging](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external)
3. ...Profit